# Contradicting statements about the Riemann zeta function at positive odd integers

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, riemann-zeta

I have found two contradicting statements about the value of $\zeta(k)$ when  $k=2n+1$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z_0^+}$. Which one is correct?

1. "*The Riemann zeta function for odd integers has no known closed-form formula*", that is, you can't find $\zeta(k)=f(k)$ such that $f$ holds for all positive odd integers. This is apparently a "well-known" fact.
2. Wikipedia states [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Series_representation_at_positive_integers_via_the_primorial) that $\zeta(k)$ can be expressed **for all positive integers, even or odd**, using the formula:

   $\zeta(k)=\frac{2^k}{2^k-1}+\sum_{r=2}^\infty\frac{(p_{r-1}\#)^k}{J_k(p_r\#)}\quad(k=2,3,\dots)$

which involves primorials and the Jordan totient function.

EDIT: I understand the above is **not a closed formula**. But then what about  [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5033), which proposes an *explicit closed-form formula*?

Comment: I wouldn't call the second expression a "closed form", so for me both are true.

Comment: Agreed. The second is no more a closed form than the definition $\zeta(k) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^k}$ is a closed form. Actually I would say it is even more opaque to me than the definition.

Comment: What about the second link then? http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5033

Comment: Isn't $\zeta(k)$ a closed formula?

Comment: The so called closed form has Dirichlet function Beta(x) . This is indeed an infinite series written as it is. So zeta,(2n+1) is indeed expressed as another infinite series, To be frank, the authors should not have claimed this as closed form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper you link to proposes "closed forms" of the type

$$\zeta(3)=\frac{2^3}{2^3-1}\beta(3)-\dots$$

with

$$\beta(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)^s}$$

Thus the infinite term is just hidden away in the function $\beta$ (which occurs in every expression they give) and the claim of having obtained closed forms is a tall one indeed.

Comment: Is it then safe to say that there is still no closed-form formula for $\zeta(2k+1)$?

Comment: @Pickle: I'm no expert, but to me this sounds like safe bet, yes (it depends on your definition of "closed form", of course). If there is a closed form, it's certainly not to be found in that paper.

Comment: Simple and concise answer. Thanks a lot man!